# NoClassDefFoundError in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

At this point, Jetpack Compose 1.0.0-alpha05 was released. I am playing around with it. I tried to create a list of items but I got `NoClassDefFoundError` exception and not figured out why happened!

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/ui/MeasureScope$-CC;
    at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$SurfaceLayout$1$1.invoke(Surface.kt:141)
    at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$SurfaceLayout$1$1.invoke(Surface.kt)
    at androidx.compose.ui.LayoutKt$MeasuringIntrinsicsMeasureBlocks$1.measure-2MWCACw(Layout.kt:386)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performMeasure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:47)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:104)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayerWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayerWrapper.kt:67)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:104)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:104)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayerWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayerWrapper.kt:67)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:91)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:133)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.observeMeasureModelReads(AndroidComposeView.kt:473)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:90)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:63)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNode.kt:1228)
    at androidx.compose.ui.RootMeasureBlocks.measure-2MWCACw(RootMeasureBlocks.kt:36)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performMeasure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:47)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:104)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:104)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:104)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:104)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:104)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayerWrapper.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayerWrapper.kt:67)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:123)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:91)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$2.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:1721)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:128)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.observeMeasureModelReads(AndroidComposeView.kt:473)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.remeasure-BRTryo0(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:90)
```

Also, I put the project [here](https://github.com/Kaaveh/Movie-Compose) because I don't know which part of the code must I post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error and updating all compose related libraries to version `1.0.0-alpha06` solved the issue for me.